# How to programmatically get the resolution of a window and that of the system in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, screen-resolution

I'm trying to get the resolution of the screen as well as the resolution of a specific window (in which a program is running) on Linux system. I don't need to modify the resolution, I only need the current values. As far as I know, we can call some system functions to do so on Windows, how can we do that on Linux, preferably using C/C++ language? Thanks in advance.

update: Actually, I don't need to do a GUI, although I know Qt and GTK+ can do it, I'm reluctant to include an external library for just getting the resolution.

Comment: If there's no GUI, then is it a console app? Do you need those values even when not running under X?

Comment: There is GUI, but the part I'm working on doesn't need one. It only need those values for later measurement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In X11, you'd need to call the Xlib's [XGetWindowAttributes](http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XGetWindowAttributes.3.html) to get the various window info, including the size and position relative to parent. For an example of how it is used, you can google for 'xwininfo.c'.

That said, probably you are going to use some more highlevel framework to do your window programming - and the chances are high that it already has some other primitives for this, see an example for [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.0/geometry.html) - so you might want to give a bit more background about the question.

Answer (score 9):

To get screen resolution, you can use XRandR extension, like in [xrandr](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc#GVFTOHYvCds/xc/programs/xrandr/xrandr.c&q=xrandr.c) sources:

```
  SizeID        current_size;
  XRRScreenSize *sizes;
  dpy = XOpenDisplay (display_name);
  // ...
  root = RootWindow (dpy, screen);
  sc = XRRGetScreenInfo (dpy, root);
  current_size = XRRConfigCurrentConfiguration (sc, &current_rotation);
  sizes = XRRConfigSizes(sc, &nsize);
  for (i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
    printf ("%c%-2d %5d x %-5d  (%4dmm x%4dmm )",
         i == current_size ? '*' : ' ',
         i, sizes[i].width, sizes[i].height,
         sizes[i].mwidth, sizes[i].mheight);
     // ...
  }
```

You can see the output typing "xrandr" in your xterm.

Or, better, use the [xdpyinfo](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#QlD3RqLk4t4/xdpyinfo.c&q=xdpyinfo.c) method:

```
Display *dpy;
// dpy = ...
int scr = /* ... */
printf ("  dimensions:    %dx%d pixels (%dx%d millimeters)\n",
        DisplayWidth (dpy, scr), DisplayHeight (dpy, scr),
        DisplayWidthMM(dpy, scr), DisplayHeightMM (dpy, scr));
```

Comment: RandR is more detailed than DisplayWidth/DisplayHeight, but both are useful (for different reasons).

Comment: As far as I know, `DisplayWidht`/`DisplayHeight` can only list the current screen size. They are not meant to list all available screen sizes (display modes). That's what `Xrandr` or `XF86vm` are for.

Comment: Short question: Does the `sizes` array returned (as an address) from `XRRConfigSizes` require freeing later on? Or is it allocated and managed internally by the library? I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation (if there is any, beyond the skimpy manpage).

Comment: I have found DisplayWidth/DisplayHeight and XDisplayWidth and XDisplayHeight to be inaccurate while xrandr appear to be accurate.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: RandR is the way. The “screen” is just a rectangle that encompasses all monitors but they may not actually form a rectangular shape (especially if they have different sizes). And as monitors may have different DPI, physical screen size doesn’t make any sense at all (and is always calculated as 96 DPI nowadays).

Answer (score 6):

Depends:

- If you're hardcore and you want to use Xlib, have a look at XDisplayWidth() and XDisplayHeight().
- If you use Qt4 (my preference), try

  ```
   QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry()
  ```

  (see http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.0/qdesktopwidget.html )
- Or in Gtk, see http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/GdkScreen.html

Comment: Can Qt or Gtk+ get a specific window's resolution?

Comment: I can get a list of windows with GTK, but no name, id or anything. No idea how to identify a specific window. Eventually went for Xlib, and solved my problem (though the code looks a bit disgusting...).

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool xdpyinfo provides this information for you; to do it programmatically you need to to use Xlib, as Andrew Y explains.