# Programmaticaly check if user is in desktop - Linux

Tags: linux, size, desktop

i am making a program which needs to be run in desktop mode. How can I check in C? And also, is it possible to get screen width and height in C(of the monitor)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153052/how-to-programmatically-get-the-resolution-of-a-window-and-that-of-the-system-in

Comment: so there is nothing like GetSystemMetrics(), like in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but I'll bite. I'm assuming that by "desktop mode" you mean a running [X window system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). Since you don't seem to have a preferred widget toolkit, I'll show an example which uses Xlib.

You could simply try to open the display and check the return value. If it's up, you can retrieve the screen resolution as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int screen_num;
    unsigned int display_width, display_height;
    Display *display;

    /* First connect to the display server, as specified in the DISPLAY 
       environment variable. */
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!display)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to connect to display");
        return 1;
    }

    /* pull useful data out of the display object */
    screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);

    /* Display size is a member of display structure */
    display_width = DisplayWidth(display, screen_num);
    display_height = DisplayHeight(display, screen_num);

    fprintf(stdout, "resolution is %d x %d\n", display_width, display_height);

    return 0;
}
```

You have to compile with `-lX11`. All of this and much more can be learned from [the Xlib programming tutorial here](http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Jan/Xlib-tutorial-part-1----Beginnings.html).